# Задача из олимпиады по программировании

Tags: python

Можете дать хотя бы формулу для выполнении этой задачи?
Для печати первой энциклопедии всего на свете, царь тридевятого царства заказал у кузнеца отлить шрифты и буквицы. В том числе было отлито N цифр, необходимых для набора и печати номеров страниц. Один наборщик делает ровно K макетов страниц в день. Написать программу, которая определит, какое минимальное количество наборщиков нужно, чтобы закончить набор всех страниц за три дня.

Формат ввода
В единственной строке входных данных задано два числа N и K: 10 < N <1010 – количество отпечатанных цифр, 0 < К < 11 – количество страниц, набираемых одним наборщиком в день.

Формат вывода
В качестве выходных данных выведите одно число – минимальное количество наборщиков необходимых чтобы закончить работу в срок.

Comment: Хотя бы формула - почти решение. Расскажите, пожалуйста, что вы пытались сделать и что конкретно не получилось. Всегда видел, что на этом сайте заведено так делать, а ваш случай - незавуалированная лень.

Comment: @mrEvgenX , Не получилось понять каким образом выходит минимальное количство наборищиков. Пробирая все цифры в калькуляторе и хоть как то думая как это сделать, не получилось толком ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Ключ к решению этой задачи — определить количество страниц для набора, зная количество цифр для их нумерации. (Были заказаны ровно те цифры, которые для этого нужны).

- Первые 9 страниц тратят по одной цифре.
- Следующие 90 страниц тратят по две цифры.
- Следующие 900 страниц тратят по три цифры.
- и т.д.

<sub>*Один из вариантов решения можно посмотреть в истории изменений*</sub>